# Android proxy server

Tags: java, android, proxy-server

I want to make android as proxy server that i can use to as a proxy server by using ip address and port no that will by pass and hide my laptop ip address.

The case is:

1. My android phone is connected via data network and should work like proxy server.
2. Have a java program that will set the proxy server ip address and port that will open a Chrom Browser using selenium.
3. Laptop running java program connected via some other network rather than phone network.

Now I want the hit should be anonymous, Current browser ip should not be tracked as i am using proxy server.

Need tech help, or any way to achieve the same.

Comment: did you find any answer @Uma Shanker

Comment: i found it for any one who want the answer pls check this link https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/848#